# Databind and validate a TableViewer?

Tags: java, data-binding, jface

I use the `org.eclipse.core.databinding` framework to bind some `Text` fields in an SWT application. I add an update strategy to validate the data and to set the value on the model only when the user click on the save button:

```
    UpdateValueStrategy toModel = new UpdateValueStrategy(UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_CONVERT);
    if (validator != null) {
        toModel.setAfterGetValidator(validator);
    }

    UpdateValueStrategy fromModel = new UpdateValueStrategy(UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_UPDATE);

    binding = bindingContext.bindValue(SWTObservables.observeText(this, SWT.Modify),
                    BeansObservables.observeValue(pVO, propertyName), toModel, fromModel);
```

This piece of code works really well.

But how can I do the same on a `TableViewer`?

I want it to work so that when I add something in the IHM, the model stay unchanged until I call `getBindingContext().updateModels();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need use the JFace Databinding Framework in `TableViewer`. Manipulation the structured data is simpler then SWT controls, such `TableViewer`, `ListViewer` and `TreeViewer`. You can use those viewer in the same way:

- create viewer
- set content provider
- set label provider (suggested)
- set filter (optional)
- set sorter (optional)

After the viewer created, just invoke `viewer.setInput(data)` to put all the things to  your viewer.

There are a list of model:

```
TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(parent); 

Table table = tableViewer.getTable(); 
table.setHeaderVisible(true);      
table.setLinesVisible(true);`

for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_NAMES.length; i++) {
    TableColumn tableColumn = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    tableColumn.setText(COLUMN_NAMES[i]);
    tableColumn.setWidth(COLUMN_WIDTHS[i]);
}

tableViewer.setContentProvider(new ModelContentProvider());
tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new ModelLabelProvider());
tableViewer.setInput(models);
```

The magic happens in the content provider:

```
class ModelContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        // The inputElement comes from view.setInput()
        if (inputElement instanceof List) {
            List models = (List) inputElement;
            return models.toArray();
        }
        return new Object[0];
    }

/* ... other methods */

}
```

Each model will become a `TableItem` and the model in the `TableItem(item.getData())`.

However, a table composed by many columns, you need the `LabelProvider` to help you mapping the property of model to the `TableItem`:

```
class ModelLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements
        ITableLabelProvider {

    @Override
    public Image getColumnImage(Object element, int columnIndex) {
        // no image to show
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex) {
        // each element comes from the ContentProvider.getElements(Object)
        if (!(element instanceof Model)) {
            return "";
        }
        Model model = (Model) element;
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return model.getFoo();
        case 1:
            return model.getBar();
        default:
            break;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

The propagation of models to viewer is easy. If you will propagate viewer to the binded model, using the `CellEditor` is simple as well.
To use `CellEditor`, you need set the column properties,  cell editors and cell modifier  to `TableViewer`:

```
tableViewer.setColumnProperties(COLUMNS_PROPERTIES);
tableViewer.setCellEditors(new CellEditor[] {
        new TextCellEditor(table), new TextCellEditor(table) });
tableViewer.setCellModifier(new ModelCellModifier(tableViewer));
```

The CellModifier likes this:

```
class ModelCellModifier implements ICellModifier {
    TableViewer viewer;

    public ModelCellModifier(TableViewer viewer) {
        this.viewer = viewer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canModify(Object element, String property) {
        // property is defined by viewer.setColumnProperties()
        // allow the FOO column can be modified.
        return "foo_prop".equals(property);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(Object element, String property) {
        if ("foo_prop".equals(property)) {
            return ((Model) element).getFoo();
        }
        if ("bar_prop".equals(property)) {
            return ((Model) element).getBar();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void modify(Object element, String property, Object value) {
        if ("foo_prop".equals(property)) {
            TableItem item = (TableItem) element;
            ((Model) item.getData()).setFoo("" + value);

            // refresh the viewer to show the changes to our user.
            viewer.refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is simple but there are many steps to make all together.

Comment: ...but why would you want to give up on databinding and return to writing lots of boilerplate code?

Comment: Small comment: `tableViewer.setColumnProperties(COLUMNS_PROPERTIES);` means that in `COLUMN_PROPERTIES` you have to give all column names - or just use `COLUMN_NAMES` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use ViewerSupport:

```
TableViewer tableViewer = ...
IObservableList tableElements = ...
IValueProperty[] columnProperties = ...
ViewerSupport.bind(tableViewer, tableElements, columnProperties);
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution. But is there some way to use validators and converters with a table viewer with this?

Answer (score 0):

i agree with qualidafial.

`Snippet017TableViewerWithDerivedColumns` from the `jface.databinding` snippets is a full example of this.

Comment: The snippet doesn't seem to be available any more. Here is an alternative: http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding/Snippets#Viewers